# React-Native: run a function in background while component is loaded

Tags: javascript, react-native, backgroundworker, web-worker

In a component, while the listview and everything is loaded.

Is it possible to run a function in background to reload the listview data in every few minutes?

If yes, 
When user leaves the component ( go to another tab, iOS ), will the function stop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this by adding a setInterval in componentDidMount and clearing it in componentWillUnmount.

```
let interval;
class HelloWorld extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    interval = setInterval(() => {

        // do what you want here.

    }, 10000);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(interval);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Text>Hello world!</Text>
    );
  }
}
```